# Image getting clipped inside circle and re-positioning after scaling

Tags: html, css

I want to display images as circle on my webpage. For that, I have an image set as background wrapped inside a div container. Both the divs (outer and inner) have been given a border radius of 50% to achieve this. I also want the image to zoom in oh hover, for which I have applied transform:scale on the inner div.

The image is getting clipped a bit from left and right sides so it doesn't appear as a perfect circle. However, when the image gets scaled up on hover, the image forms a perfect circle. I have tried re-positioning it with background position, tried using a bigger image, increased/decreased size of both divs, but no method is working.

Further, when the image gets zoomed in on hover (using transform:scale), it gets re-positioned slightly after the transformation is complete. Strangely, if I remove the transition effect (transition duration and transition-timing-function), then this re-positioning doesn't happen.

Can anybody figure out why this is happening and what is the solution?
I am using bootstrap (I know it has a class img-circle which draws circle, but I wish to use my own code).

You can see the code running here: http://jsfiddle.net/dk49/h9KZr/

Observe the clipping of image on left and right sides of the circle and how it gets into correct shape on hovering over it. You can also see the jittering of image on zooming when hovering over it.

```
<div class="container-fluid page-content-wrapper"> 

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
    <div class="circle-container">
        <h2 class="img-header">Men</h2>
        <div class="inner-circle img-men"></div>
    </div>  
</div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.page-content-wrapper {
    max-width: 980px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #000;
}

.circle-container {
    max-width: 325px;
    max-height:325px; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
    z-index: 5; /* for fixing chrome bug */
}

.inner-circle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative; 
    transition: transform 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.inner-circle:hover, .inner-circle:active { 
    transform: scale(1.1); 
}

.circle-container:hover .img-header, .circle-container:active .img-header{
    bottom: 30%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}

.img-header {
    color: #fff;
    bottom: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    color: #000;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 7px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 43px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: bottom 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.img-header:hover ~ .inner-circle, .img-header:active ~ .inner-circle  {
    transform: scale(1.1); 
}

.img-men {
    background: url(http://s8.postimg.org/qohfig4md/men.png) center center no-repeat;   
    background-size: contain; 

}
```

Comment: A jsfiddle that shows your issue would be nice.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xzfbH like this ?

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/dk49/h9KZr/

Comment: Update: the repositioning/flickering of image on zooming is happening only in Firefox. But image is getting slightly clipped in all browsers.